# How do I encapsulate object constructors and destructors in haskell

Tags: c++, c, haskell

I have Haskell code which needs to interface with a C library somewhat like this:

```
// MyObject.h
typedef struct MyObject *MyObject;
MyObject newMyObject(void);
void myObjectDoStuff(MyObject myObject);
//...
void freeMyObject(MyObject myObject);
```

The original FFI code wraps all of these functions as pure functions using `unsafePerformIO`. This has caused bugs and inconsistencies because the sequencing of the operations is undefined.

What I am looking for is a general way of dealing with objects in Haskell without resorting to doing everything in `IO`. What would be nice is something where I can do something like:

```hs
myPureFunction :: String -> Int
-- create object, call methods, call destructor, return results
```

Is there a nice way to achieve this?

Comment: Well, I guess wrap them as `IO` functions, chain them together in whatever fashion you need and *then* do `unsafePerformIO` on the resulting action?

Comment: Is there a different monad other than resorting to IO which I could use which would achieve the same effect? Because the way I see it this isn't IO per se, it's mutable state. I have a feeling I could use a state monad or something but I'm nervous about the order being rearranged...

Comment: @grasevski IO is really a monomorphic state monad. This would work.

Comment: @grasevski This is really what IO was built for.  Basically any function that interacts with the computer (i.e. doesn't just calculate something) has to access a platform specific API.  Printing to STDOUT means calling the platform specific kernel function that actually prints it, it isn't a Haskell "primitive".  The encouraged action is to use IO when accessing the outside world.  If you're 110% sure that the functions you access don't have side effects, then go ahead and wrap them in `unsafePerformIO`, but otherwise stick to the IO monad.  That's my $0.02

Comment: This is mostly semantics, but the c code doesn't really touch the outside world, it is just functions which change mutable state, given as input. This is like in haskell with STRef etc. I was hoping that, like how one can use STRef rather than IORef for mutable state in haskell, there is some analog in my situation.

Comment: I.e. I'd rather separate this code (using the type system) from code which changes the outside world if possible

Comment: @grasevski how is a destructor call not changing the outside world?

Comment: @Cubic how is it? There is no observable effect to the user, hence why people feel it is ok to use unsafePerformIO in FFI code in the first place. You expect there to be no actual IO (printf, putstrln etc, which is what the IO monad is actually for), so for all of these libraries on hackage eg libsvm, gsl etc things are wrapped in unsafePerformIO and exported as pure functions. See my answer below for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My final solution. It probably has subtle bugs that I haven't considered, but it is the only solution so far which has met all of the original criteria:

- Strict - all operations are sequenced correctly
- Abstract - the library is exported as a stateful monad rather than a leaky set of IO operations
- Safe - the user can embed this code in pure code without using unsafePerformIO and they can expect the result to be pure

Unfortunately the implementation is a bit complicated.

E.g.

```
// Stack.h
typedef struct Stack *Stack;
Stack newStack(void);
void pushStack(Stack, int);
int popStack(Stack);
void freeStack(Stack);
```

c2hs file:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
module CStack(StackEnv(), runStack, pushStack, popStack) where
import Foreign.C.Types
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.ForeignPtr
import qualified Foreign.Marshal.Unsafe
import qualified Control.Monad.Reader
#include "Stack.h"
{#pointer Stack foreign newtype#}

newtype StackEnv a = StackEnv
 (Control.Monad.Reader.ReaderT (Ptr Stack) IO a)
 deriving (Functor, Monad)

runStack :: StackEnv a -> a
runStack (StackEnv (Control.Monad.Reader.ReaderT m))
 = Foreign.Marshal.Unsafe.unsafeLocalState $ do
  s <- {#call unsafe newStack#}
  result <- m s
  {#call unsafe freeStack#} s
  return result

pushStack :: Int -> StackEnv ()
pushStack x = StackEnv . Control.Monad.Reader.ReaderT $
 flip {#call unsafe pushStack as _pushStack#} (fromIntegral x)

popStack :: StackEnv Int
popStack = StackEnv . Control.Monad.Reader.ReaderT $
 fmap fromIntegral . {#call unsafe popStack as _popStack#}
```

test program:

```hs
-- Main.hs
module Main where
import qualified CStack
main :: IO ()
main = print $ CStack.runStack x where
 x :: CStack.StackEnv Int
 x = pushStack 42 >> popStack
```

build:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -c Stack.c
$ c2hs CStack.chs
$ ghc --make -Wall -Werror Main.hs Stack.o
$ ./Main
42
```

Answer (score 5):

The idea is to keep passing a baton from each component to force each component to be evaluated in sequence. This is basically what the state monad is (`IO` is really a weird state monad. Kinda).

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
import Control.Monad.State

data Baton = Baton -- Hide the constructor!

newtype CLib a = CLib {runCLib :: State Baton a} deriving Monad
```

And then you just string operations together. Injecting them into the `CLib` monad will mean they're sequenced. Essentially, you're faking your own `IO`, in a more unsafe way since you can escape.

Then you must ensure that you add `construct` and `destruct` to the end of all `CLib` chains. This is easily done by exporting a function like

```hs
clib :: CLib a -> a
clib m = runCLib $ construct >> m >> destruct
```

The last big hoop to jump through is to make sure that when you `unsafePerformIO` whatever's in `construct`, it actually gets evaluated.

---

Frankly, this is all kinda pointless since it already exists, battle proven in `IO`. Instead of this whole elaborate process, how about just

```hs
construct :: IO Object
destruct  :: IO ()
runClib :: (Object -> IO a) -> a
runClib = unsafePerformIO $ construct >>= m >> destruct
```

If you don't want to use the name `IO`:

```hs
newtype CLib a = {runCLib :: IO a} deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)
```

Comment: Would it still work if I replaced IO with ST? So that I can enforce that the IO code is separate from this. Otherwise someone could easily come along and put a bunch of putstrlns etc in my code and make it harder to test.

Comment: @grasevski Not really. You original operations are already inside `IO`, that's the whole point here. You don't really want `ST` because you're not trying to offer mutable fields and junk, it's orthogonal. I'd suggest creating a custom wrapper like I showed in my last line of code. Basically you're attempting to avoid `unsafePerformIO`-ing individual operations and instead doing it to one complete computation.

Comment: @jozefg you may need to use `Control.Monad.State.Strict` for this.  Also, you don't even need a separate baton, you can have the state be `Ptr MyObject` and pass that in to every function at each step.  Although the pointer shouldn't change, so you could instead use a 'Reader'.  Of course there are a lot of ways to accomplish this...

Comment: What I want is to isolate changes to the mutable c state in a monad separate from the rest of IO. This does not achieve this because it is leaky abstraction. What would be good is to have my FFI module export some functions like `clib :: CLib a -> a`, `clibX :: CLib Int`, `clibY :: Int -> CLib ()`, etc. I attempted this with `unsafeLocalState` and `Control.Monad.State.Strict` but it doesnt work for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I've never actually worked with C stuff from Haskell, so I am not speaking from experience here.

But what springs to mind for me is to write something like:

```
withMyObject :: NFData r => My -> Object -> Constructor -> Params -> (MyObject -> r) -> r
```

You wrap the C++ constructor/destructor as IO operations. `withMyObject` uses IO to sequence the constructor, calling the user-specified function, calling the destructor, and returning the result. It can then `unsafePerformIO` that entire `do` block (as opposed to the individual operations within it, which you've already cooking doesn't work). You need to use `deepSeq` too (which is why the `NFData` constraint is there), or laziness could defer the use of the `MyObject` until after it's been destructed.

The advantages of this is are:

1. You can write pure `MyObject -> r` functions using whatever ordinary code you like, no monads required
2. You can decide to construct a `MyObject` in order to call such functions in the middle of other ordinary pure code, with the help of `withMyObject`
3. You can't forget to call the destructor when you use `withMyObject`
4. You can't use the `MyObject` after calling the destructor on it<sup>1</sup>
5. There is only one (small) place in your system where you use `unsafePerformIO`, and therefore that's the only place you have to carefully worry about whether you've got the sequencing correct to justify that it's safe after all. There's also only one place you have to worry about making sure you use the destructor properly.

It's basically the "construct, use, destruct" pattern with the particulars of the "use" step abstracted out as a parameter so that you can has a single implementation cover every time you need to use that pattern.

The main disadvantage is that it's a bit awkward to construct a `MyObject` and then pass it to several unrelated functions. You have to bundle them up into a function that returns a tuple of each of the original results, and then use `withMyObject` on that. Alternatively if you also expose the `IO` versions of he constructor and destructor separately the user has the option of using those if `IO` is less awkward than making wrapper functions to pass to `withMyObject` (but then it's possible for the user to accidentally use the `MyObject` after freeing it, or forget to free it).

---

<sup>1</sup> Unless you do something silly like use `id` as the `MyObject -> r` function. Presumably there's no `NFData MyObject` instance though. Also that sort of error would tend to come from willful abuse rather than accidental misunderstanding.